# How does app know if it started from a crash

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle

Whenever I start the app I want to know if the app recovered from a crash. Can I store it in a flag ?

Do the crash and regular app exit scenario go through the same steps(lifecycle) in android ?

Answer (score 1):

You can override your crash exception by using Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler. But do not forget, If you would not close your application it will freeze the screen by OS.
Example code :

```
//variable that inside the application class
private Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler defaultUEH;
public void onCreate(){
    super.onCreate();
    defaultUEH = Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler();
    Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler(){
            @Override
            public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {
                handleUncaughtException(t,e);
                defaultUEH.uncaughtException(thread,e);  
            }
        });
}

private void handleUncaughtException(Thread thread,Throwable e){
      //do whatever you like!

}
```

**NOTE :** There is no way to understand how is your program is opened

Answer (score 0):

You don't get this information at all from the Android SDK. There are two options you could try, first is would be to have extensive logging/tracking of the apps life-cycle. In all of your activities keep track of when you activities are started, resumed, paused, stopped, and destroyed. (Also handle special usecase of when the device is rotated and the activity will experience a tear-down and restart). From here you will have information of when an activity has been stopped and you check the last state in the onCreate, onStart, or onResume of you activities to make sure that you're expected life-cycles where hit. If not, then you more than likely experienced a crash. Also note, on older version of Android certain teardown life-cycle callbacks weren't guaranteed to be called.

Second option would be to try using [Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html#setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler%28java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler%29). I have never personally used it but it may help in the usecase where an uncaught exception occurs. You could log such an event and check that flag once, the app is resumed. I am not sure of all of the side effects of using this mechanism such as, will this override the default uncaught exception behavior and remove the default stack trace that gets printed out, which would be **very very very bad**.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way for the app to know whether it started from a crash; this is indistinguishable from starting the application for the first time after booting. In both cases you will see the onCreate [lifecycle event](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html) for your activity.

If your application crashes, it stops processing lifecycle events. So no, lifecycle events will not be processed in the same way.

If you want to know whether your application is crashing, perhaps a better approach is to directly record when the application crashes. There are tools like [Errbit](https://errbit.com/) that help record this when the application is running on general users' devices.

Answer (score -1):

Try to add Exception handling to the code to whatever is causing a crash.

```
try{
   //code causing the crash
} catch (Exception e){
   //code to set flags whenever an event causing crash occurs.
}
```